# about completion of a metric space

Tags: general-topology

Is the following proposition true? If yes, how would you prove this?

**Proposition :**
Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and let $(\widetilde{X},\widetilde{d})$ be a completion of $(X,d)$
then if : $Y\subset \widetilde{X}$ and $\overline{Y}=\widetilde{X} \Rightarrow X=Y.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s clearly false. Let $X=\Bbb Q$ with the usual metric; then $\widetilde{X}=\Bbb R$ with the usual metric. Let $Y=\Bbb Q\cup\{\pi\}$; clearly $\operatorname{cl}Y=\Bbb R$, but $Y\ne\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Amine: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @BriaMScott  if the condition $Y\subset \widetilde{X}$ and $\overline{Y}=\widetilde{X}$ is changed by $Y\subset \widetilde{X}$ and $\overline{X}=Y$

Comment: @Amine: $X$ is dense in its completion, so if $\operatorname{cl}X=Y$, then $Y=\widetilde{X}$.

Comment: @BrianMScott it's easy, thank you very much

Comment: @Amine: You’re welcome!